# What is the difference between logInWithReadPermissions and logInWithPublishPermissions in Facebook SDK(v4.12.0) for android?

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

Creating an application which uses Facebook Sign In and then Facebook profile ID as identifier for logged in User.

But, Login manager, which is supposed to be the class used for loging in, has logInWithReadPermissions as well as logInWithPublishPermissions. The names sound words apart.

The documentation says nothing about what do they do. Which one should I use??